# Stuck on "Waiting for SSH to be available" when creating Docker Machine from Ubuntu to RaspberryPi

Tags: docker, ubuntu, ssh, raspberry-pi, docker-machine

I cannot create a new docker machine to Raspberry Pi as I keep getting error after the following:

```
docker-machine create --engine-storage-driver overlay2 --driver gemeroc --generic-ssh-user pi --generic-ip-address (ip address of the Pi) badgelab

Running pre-create checks...
Creating machine
Waiting for machine to be running, this may take a few minutes...
Detecting operating system of created instance...
Waiting for SSH to be available
Error creating machine: Error detecting OS: Too many retries waiting for SSH to be available. Last error: Maximum number of retries (60) exceeded
```

The SSH works as I can connect to the badge no problem and I have done everything according to this guide and several other guides: https://rux.vc/2020.01/installing-docker-machine-on-raspberry-pi/

Answer (score 0):

Check if this is similar to the recent (May 2020) [`docker/machine` issue 4809](https://github.com/docker/machine/issues/4809)

One command which seemed to be working was adding  `--generic-ssh-key`:

```
docker-machine create -d generic --generic-ssh-user admin --generic-ip-address "82.151.200.105" --generic-ssh-key
```

You can also try `--native-ssh`, to switch to the SSH Go implementation, in case it makes a difference in your case.